# Printing console message when QPushButton is pressed

Tags: python, pyqt4, qpushbutton

I am new to Python and I want to do a simple code to print a message in the Python console when a QPushButton is pressed. I split the code in 2 .py files (one for UI and the other for the main application). Although it supposed to be very simple, I still didn't manage to make it work.

I am pretty sure that this is a beginner mistake but I cant find what is wrong when I check answers from related posts or even compared with similar code from other posts in this forum.

The "Test from main!", "Test from main - 2nd time!" and "Test from edit!" printing lines appeared on the console but I dont know why the other two are not called when the button are clicked. I am guessing i am doing something wrong with the clicked.connect() method.

Tank you all very much.

The file's code is the following:

The UI code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(850, 450)     

        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 251, 61))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))

        self.pushButton_Selection = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_Selection.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(148, 250, 161, 61))
        self.pushButton_Selection.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_Selection"))  

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)        

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Communication", None))        
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Print Line", None))        
        self.pushButton_Selection.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Select sensor", None))        

        print "Test from edit!"
```

The main file code:

```
import sys
import PyQt4.QtCore as QtCore
import PyQt4.QtGui as QtGui

from EditTxt_ui import Ui_Dialog

print "Test from main!"

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.print_LineEdit)
        self.pushButton_Selection.clicked.connect(self.print_Selection)

    print "Test from main - 2nd time!"

    def print_LineEdit(self):
        print "Print from LineEdit!"

    def print_Selection(self):                      
        print "Print Selection!"            

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems in your code:

- You don't create an instance of the class MyForm.
- The buttons are created in the class Ui_Dialog but you try to access them from MyForm.

If you want to access the buttons in MyForm, you have to create an instance of Ui_Dialog in MyForm, like this:

```
class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.print_LineEdit)
        self.ui.pushButton_Selection.clicked.connect(self.print_Selection)

    def print_LineEdit(self):
        print "Print from LineEdit!"

    def print_Selection(self):                      
        print "Print Selection!"            

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MyForm()
    MainWindow.show()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another solution would be to put the functions print_LineEdit and print_Selection in the class Ui_Dialog.

But for a really simple application like this one, I would put everything in the main file in one class, like this:

```
import sys
import PyQt4.QtCore as QtCore
import PyQt4.QtGui as QtGui

class MyForm(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pushButton_2=QtGui.QPushButton("Print Line")
        self.pushButton_Selection=QtGui.QPushButton("Select sensor")

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.print_LineEdit)
        self.pushButton_Selection.clicked.connect(self.print_Selection)

        #layout
        vbox=QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        vbox.addWidget(self.pushButton_Selection)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def print_LineEdit(self):
        print "Print from LineEdit!"

    def print_Selection(self):                      
        print "Print Selection!"            

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MyForm()
    MainWindow.show()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

(I didn't bother with the layout but you could)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because the MyForm instance is not declared anywhere in the code. You are calling the function in that class' init but the class is not instantiated.

In these cases it is better that you create a function in the Ui_Dialog class that instantiates the class on the click of the button and call the functions in your constructor, to print the results.